# Multiplicacion de matriz en JAVA

Tags: java

TENGO UN CÓDIGO POR CLASES Y TENGO QUE HACER UNA CLASE PARA MULTIPLICAR LAS DOS MATRICES, CREE UNA TERCERA MATRIZ (NO SE SI ESTARA BIEN) PARA QUE ME IMPRIMA EL RESULTADO DE LA MUTIPLICACION DE LAS DOS MATRICES PERO NO SE COMO PLANTEARLO, TAMPOCO SE COMO LLAMAR ESE BLOQUE PARA QUE ME IMPRIMA ESE RESULTADO.
NECESITO AYUDA :(

```
static int[][] matriz1 = null;
static int[][] matriz2 = null;
static int[][] matriz3 = null;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Tarea03 control = new Tarea03();
    matriz1 = definirTamaño(matriz1);
    System.out.println("FILAS: " + matriz1.length);
    System.out.println("COLUMNAS: " + matriz1.length);
    System.out.println();
    ingresarValores(matriz1);
    System.out.println();
    imprimirMatriz(matriz1);

    System.out.println();

    matriz2 = definirTamaño(matriz2);
    System.out.println("FILAS: " + matriz2.length);
    System.out.println("COLUMNAS: " + matriz2.length);
    System.out.println();
    ingresarValores(matriz2);
    System.out.println();
    imprimirMatriz(matriz2);
}
public static int[][] definirTamaño(int[][] x) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño de la materia filas & columnas");
    String datosIngresados = sc.next();
    String[] datos = datosIngresados.split("&");
    System.out.println();
    int filas = Integer.parseInt(datos[0]);
    int columnas = Integer.parseInt(datos[1]);
    x = new int[filas][columnas];
    return x;
}
public static void ingresarValores(int[][] x) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese valores de la matriz");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            x[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        }
 public static void imprimirMatriz(int[][] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(x[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();}
```

CREE ESTE BLOQUE PARA REALIZAR LA MULTIPLICACION PERO NO SE SI ESTARA BIEN YA QUE LOS DATOS QUE INGRESO A LA MATRIZ NO SE MUY BIEN A DONDE VAN

```
       public static void multiplicación(int[][] x, matriz3[][]) {

    System.out.println("Ingrese valores de la matriz");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print((matriz1[i][j] * matriz2[i][j]) + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que implementa este código, no es un producto de matrices.

En un producto de matrices, las que se operan no tienen por qué ser cuadradas. Con tal que la primera sea gorda como alta la segunda vale. El resultado es una matriz alta como la primera u gorda como la segunda.

Parece que tu código intenta hacer el producto de una matriz por si misma. No creo que tenga mucho sentido. Si en mi caso tuviera que hacer un programa para calcular el producto de una matriz por si misma, haría un producto de matrices genérico, y en la llamada pondría dos veces la misma.